# How were streets lit at night, before street lights were invented?

Tags: ancient-rome, ancient-greece, cities

For example, how were the streets of ancient Greek cities and of ancient Rome  lit at night? I suspect that street lights as we know today didn't exist in ancient Greece and Rome, so there were other methods of street lighting at the time?

Comment: Why do you think they were lit at night? If they were, wouldn't whatever method was used be considered "street lights"?

Comment: Did you look at the Wikipedia page on [Street Lights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_light#:~:text=Early%20lamps%20were,a%20lanternarius.)?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: A [youtube vid on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yva2RpQrWQs&t=2s) just happened to hit my timeline today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Street weren't lit. It was dark.

In ancient times, you would carry light yourself or had somebody carry it for you. Be it a slave or someone offering their services for a fee.

If you didn't carry light yourself, didn't have a slave and couldn't afford to hire one: you'd be stumbling in the dark.

[Public lighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_light) started from the 16th century, when it became economically affordable and technically possible. Yes, the Romans had good enough oil lamps and even a name for one that manages oil lamps: a [lanternarius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_light#History). But those individuals would be hired/owned by wealthy individuals, for private use. Not by a city to provide public lighting.

Oil lamps as the Greeks and Romans used were a serious fire hazard. If one tipped over for whatever reason, that could cause a fire. Candles were too expensive (and almost as dangerous), torches don't last long enough, provide very little light and are a fire hazard as well.

The Torah has rules (restrictions, mainly) for lighting to prevent fires. One exception is made for Hanukkah, when people are required to light lamps and candles.

Answer (score 4):

In practice, except in inclement weather that kept most people indoors, few nights are dark enough to actually require night lighting for the purpose of general navigation of town. The three days of full moon (ie day before, day of, and day after) are nearly bright enough to read a book or newspaper by once one's eye dilate. The stars on a clear night easily provide sufficient light, in open areas, for general walking about, though I might not want to travel much faster than a walking pace under those conditions.

Unfortunately, few of us today have ever been outside urban lights long enough for our eyes to adjust. Walking the dog at my grandfather's place, decades ago in the forest, was a revelation. Stepping outside the house lights it seemed as though we were swallowed by the darkness, unable to see past our own noses. We'd stumble off by the light of a weak flashlight, only to turn it off 10 minutes later, about half way through the walk, as our eyes adjusted. Likewise, as we rounded the last corner back to the house, the house lights would blind us until our pupils again constricted a minute or two later.

The stars on those walks were magnificent, truly thousands of twinkling little lights dancing in the sky.